# Largest palindrome product - lack of generality

Tags: python-3.x

As some may notice I am referring to the [n. 4 Problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) from Project Euler. I am not really a professional but I have found this solution.
I am stuck because I can't find the correct answer to the problem; generally I would unit test and debug using lower numbers but the odd thing is that running the program trying to find the max palindrome as the product of two-digit numbers gets me *9009* which is correct.

```
def is_palindromic(number):
    number = list(str(number))
    newNumber = []
    for n in range(1, len(number)+1):
        newNumber += number[-n]
    if newNumber == number:
        return True

maxPalindrome = 0

for a in range(100, 1000):
    for b in range(100,1000):
        if(is_palindromic(a*b)):
            maxPalindrome = a*b
print("max palindrome is : {}".format(maxPalindrome))
```

I want to point out that I am not posting here for the mere purpose of finding the solution but also because it seems strange to me that the code is not general for a class of similar problems. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Your question does not seem to say why you think something is actually wrong with your code. Do you get unexpected results? If so, which?

Comment: Note that a simpler code to test for a palindrom is ``def is_palindrom(number): return str(number) == str(number)[::-1]``. There is no need to manually reverse the string (a reversed slice ``[::-1]`` does that better) and there is no need to make a *boolean* test only then to return a boolean. Either way, this does not change the result.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I apologise for omitting details. The result i get is _580085_ while the expected is _906609_.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks for the tips, cleaning and sharping my code is exactly my target rn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I was not getting the expected answer because from the way I structured the problem initially I was somehow (I don't really know why) assuming that a check on the maximum polindrome was not required since the numbers were just getting bigger and bigger with time. So the final solution is:

```
def is_palindromic(number):
    number = list(str(number))
    newNumber = number[::-1]
    return number == newNumber


maxPalindrome = 0

for a in range(100, 1000):
    for b in range(100,1000):
        if(is_palindromic(a*b)):
            if(a*b > maxPalindrome):
                maxPalindrome = a*b
print("max palindrome is : {}".format(maxPalindrome))
```

Shotout to @MisterMiyagi for code improvement